# draw on a picture CustomPainter Image loading PB

Tags: flutter

Hello I do not understand there are some lib flutter that have changed

this code work one month ago

https://gist.github.com/netsmertia/9c588f23391c781fa1eb791f0dce0768

[capture d'ecran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYMBp.png)

everything happens as if this function no longer exists

merci pour tout retour
cdl remy

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3595343e20/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_decoder.dart#L23

Comment: Convert List<int> img to  Uint8List like Uint8List.fromList(img);

Answer (score 0):

thank you but it was necessary to modify also the class
but it works but the loading time of the image is very long :-(

google often changes the lib I'm a beginner in flutter

merci remy

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var image=null;
  bool isImageloaded = false;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future <Null> init() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('img/Capture5.PNG');
    this.image = await loadImage(Uint8List.view(data.buffer));
  }

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(List<int> img) async {
    return decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.fromList(img));
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    if (image!=null) {
      print ("image fin de chargement");
      return CustomPaint(
        painter: ImageEditor(image: image),
      );
    } else {
      print ("is not Loading");
      return Center(child: Text('loading'));
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My aplly'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: _buildImage(),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6cZ.png)